# rxJava opposite for throttleFirst operator (not throttling but collecting)

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I need following operator which when element comes, starts the timer (creates window for elements) and collects them into `List` or `Observable/Flowable`. When time specified for the timer ends and no element comes, the operator doesn't send empty event. When next element comes, new timer is created and it starts to collect elements.

Rx java have Buffer and Window operator but this operators have disadvantages:

- Buffer http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html
  with signature
  `buffer(long timespan, TimeUnit unit)` almost fits but it produces events with empty list when no elements in timespan comes.
- Window http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/window.html
  with signature
  `window(long timespan, TimeUnit unit)` almost fits but it produces empty `Observables/Flowables` when no elements in timespan comes.

It is possible to filter this empty elements but I would like to avoid polluting scheduler with empty events (based on the timer) with `List/Observable-s/Flowable-s`.

I spend some time and found very similar formally, but functionally fulfilling the opposite role
`throttleFirst(long windowDuration, TimeUnit unit)`
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/ReactiveX/RxJava/images/rx-operators/throttleFirst.png

But unfortunately it throttles, but not collect items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think one could save on object creation so if you want to avoid empty lists, filter them out.

As for starting a new periodic timer when a new item arrives late, I can't think of any combination of existing operators that could do it without possibly losing items.

I created the following "contraption" that could do it without item loss:

```java
public static final class BufferWithTimeout<T> {

    Scheduler.Worker trampoline = Schedulers.trampoline().createWorker();

    final long timeout;
    
    final TimeUnit unit;
    
    final Scheduler.Worker worker;
    
    final SerialDisposable timer = new SerialDisposable();
    
    final PublishSubject<List<T>> output = PublishSubject.create();
    
    List<T> current;
    
    long bufferIndex;
    
    BufferWithTimeout(long timeout, TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler) {
        this.worker = scheduler.createWorker();
        this.timeout = timeout;
        this.unit = unit;
    }
    
    void onValue(T value) {
        trampoline.schedule(() -> {
            if (timer.isDisposed()) {
                return;
            }
            if (current == null) {
                current = new ArrayList<>();
                long bi = ++bufferIndex;
                timer.set(worker.schedulePeriodically(() -> {
                    onTime(bi);
                }, timeout, timeout, unit));
            }
            current.add(value);
        });
    }

    void onTime(long index) {
        trampoline.schedule(() -> {
            if (index == bufferIndex && current != null) {
                if (current.isEmpty()) {
                    current = null;
                    bufferIndex++;
                    timer.set(null);
                } else {
                    output.onNext(current);
                    current = new ArrayList<>();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    void onTerminate(Throwable error) {
        timer.dispose();
        worker.dispose();
        trampoline.schedule(() -> {
            if (current != null && !current.isEmpty()) {
                output.onNext(current);
                current = null;
            }
            if (error != null) {
                output.onError(error);
            } else {
                output.onComplete();
            }
        });
    }
    
    void dispose() {
        timer.dispose();
        worker.dispose();
        trampoline.schedule(() -> {
            current = null;
        });
    }

    public static <T> ObservableTransformer<T, List<T>> create(
            long timeout, TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler) {
        return o -> 
            Observable.defer(() -> {
                BufferWithTimeout<T> state = new BufferWithTimeout<>(
                    timeout, unit, scheduler);

                return  o
                        .doOnNext(v -> state.onValue(v))
                        .doOnError(e -> state.onTerminate(e))
                        .doOnComplete(() -> state.onTerminate(null))
                        .ignoreElements()
                        .<List<T>>toObservable()
                        .mergeWith(state.output.doOnDispose(state::dispose));
            });
    }
}
```

You could try it via:

```java
// generate events over time
        Observable.fromArray(1, 2, 3, 5, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31)
        .flatMap(v -> Observable.timer(v * 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).map(w -> v))

// apply operator
        .compose(BufferWithTimeout.create(
             700, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.computation()
        ))

// wait for it all
        .blockingSubscribe(System.out::println);
```

Note though that this creates way more objects per source element, there is way around it but it would get way more complicated.

Comment: This code looks very low-level for the client.
Since you are the one who closed my question in rx https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/7185 I suppose that you are related with rx - team. 
I'd like to ask: Probable this is necessary to create native rx operator for this one? What do you think?

Comment: I suppose that noone will provide better code that this so I am going to accept this answer. But the question for native operator is still exist.

Comment: This pattern requires lower level constructs given the constraints. The pattern is uncommon so it is not a good fit for RxJava proper.

Answer (score 0):

What would you like to happen instead of the `onComplete`? Could you combine a `buffer()` or `window()` with a `switchIfEmpty()`?

```
//No emissions or on complete
source.window(...).switchIfEmpty(Observable.never());
```

or

```
//Empty list emission
source.window(...).switchIfEmpty(Observable.just(Collections.emptyList()));
```

Comment: Yes, I could just filter `.filter(e -> !e.isEmpty())` in case of buffer or not to react on empty `Observable` but in this case scheduler is sending empty events (based on the timer) which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: We might be referring to different things when we say "empty" - do you mean "empty" as in "emits an empty list", or "empty" as it "source observable fires `onComplete()`"? Because I'm interpreting your situation as being buffer/window is invoking `onComplete()` when there are no emissions within the operator's time frame.

Comment: I mean empty list. I've updated the description. buffer doesn't call `onComplete()` on empty events. Buffer call `onNext()` with empty list.